# What color is "vert Anglais"?

Tags: traduction, étymologie, adjectifs

I am shopping for a bicycle which is available in "vert Anglais" but I'm having a hard time finding out exactly which colors could be considered "vert Anglais". I am also interested in the etymology.

Comment: 'Vert anglais' means different things depending on the context but quite explicit when talking about cars. I guess if you google images for 'vert anglais cars' you should get a good idea of what the bike should look like

Comment: I would describe that colour as "forest green" or "racing green".

Answer (score 2):

You can find your answer here: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vert_anglais

I don't know your fluency in French so I provide below a translation of (some parts of) the lemma (I used Google Translate for convenience).

> English green is a trade name covering several shades of green and
> several pigments and preparations.
>
> Currently, it seems that the English green evokes, as far as
> automobile paints are concerned, the British Racing Green of old
> racing cars; for fine arts and decoration (...)
>
> “English green is the color green which exists in commerce under the
> greatest number of varieties; it is a complex product formed from
> arsenate of copper (Scheele's green) and several white materials such
> as sulphate of baryte and sulphate of lime. (...) The more beautiful
> has an apple-green tint, and the lower quality is leaf-dead. "
>
> - Color chemistry, 18552.
>
> The best quality shade and composition are very similar to Veronese
> green.
>
> The name English green is attested, as a commercial color, in the
> Panckoucke Encyclopedia in 1784, shortly after Scheele's invention,
> in 1775. English green is classified in light greens. According to
> another source, English green is a "mixture of lead chromate and
> Prussian blue with varying proportion of baryte sulfate" and is also
> found in the mid-19th century as Cinnabar vert, while sometimes the
> same name designates Scheele's green or another composition with the
> latter called mineral green. Milory green is also sometimes called
> English green, the recipe of which is kept secret.
>
> The name English green is quickly and constantly used in fashion,
> meaning a green that is sometimes light and often dark. This green
> is made by mixing blue and yellow pigments.
>
> The toxicity of English green made it first forbidden, in France, in
> the preparation of candies, pastilles, dragees and liqueurs, before
> having it replaced, in the color charts of color merchants, by
> mixtures of other pigments, forming the desired shades of green. On
> the other hand, we find, for horticulture, the so-called English green
> preparations used as a pesticide.
>
> In the mid-nineteenth century, the chemist Leclaire offered artists
> two English greens: light English green and dark English green, both
> zinc-based11. Before the end of the century, the name English green no
> longer referred to a pigment or a well-defined shade. From 1876 to
> 1930 Lefranc sold six English green colors.

> (...)

See also here: https://www.google.com/search?q=vert+anglais&rlz=1C1DIMA_enFR786FR786&sxsrf=ALeKk011K9EDZzo9aRlAkQgbCLgHlGzMRw:1602747601696&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvrNqLjLbsAhXk6OAKHakUDJ4Q_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1536&bih=722

HTH:-)!